# Converting GK Northing / Easting into WGS 84 coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a list of points in Excel where the header says GK Northing and Easting. I assume they are referring to the Gauss Kruger coordinate system.

```
Example:
GK Hochwert: 3497041
GK Rechtswert 5737303
```

How can I convert from this reference system to WGS 84? I have QGIS and Alteryx to perform this task.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you didn't mix up the values? Because it looks like you did.

Assuming you did mix the values up, you can [load your points into QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/supported_data.html#delimited-text-files) using [EPSG:31467](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/dhdn-gauss-kruger-zone-3/), then they should display properly. Then use `Add geometry attributes` based on WGS 84 and save the output as CSV.

If you didn't mix up the values, use [EPSG:31469](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31469/), and your points would be somewhere in the mediterranean sea?

Comment: You are right, I mixed up Rechts- and Hochwert.

Comment: I converted via Alteryx and in the output CSV file I have the coordinates 895607925174524 and 517699042713254 for the respective Rechtswert/Hochwert coordinates. This doesn't seem to be correct. QGIS shows the right points, but if I save the file with WGS 84 the output still contains the GK coordiantes.

Comment: How did you save the WGS 84 file?

Comment: Right click on the layer, export, save as ...

Comment: "Save as" in which data type? - I added an additional step which should help you.

Comment: Using "Save As", you can choose the CRS for the output. But this will not change the original attribute table values. The WGS84 coordinates are stored additionally as geometry values.

Comment: Thank you very much! One additional question: I have points all across Germany so I touch different GK zones, correct? How do I make sure that every point is loaded correctly in its respective CRS?

Comment: It would be better, if you posted this as a new, follow-up question, with a link to this one. That way question and answer would be more distinguishable from the question you posted here. Also, feel free to mark answers as correct and helpful if they are, in order to help others along when seeking help.